# Python lambda function not in condition

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

This code is reading a `csv` file into a `pandas framework`.

**Question**: Does the following `lambda function` translates to: If the `OrderNumber` has at least 4 characters, is `not substring of` "00010000" or "01000010" and it does not contain the substring "12345" then leave it as is, and remove single spaces; otherwise set it to empty string ""

```py
import sqlalchemy as sq
import pandas as pd

data_df = pd.read_csv('myDataFile.csv')

data_df['OrderNumber'] = data_df['OrderNumber'].apply(
    lambda x: x if len(x)> 4 and 
    x not in ('00010000','01000010') and 
    ('12345') not in x else '').apply(lambda x: x.replace(' ',''))
```

Comment: You say `lent`?

Comment: Why not replace `" ",""` at first place rather than using a second lambda function?

Comment: Once a lambda expression gets that long, you probably just want to use a `def` statement to create a named function, at least to define a predicate `p` so you can write `lambda x: x if p(x) else ''`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```py
data_df.OrderNumber = (
    data_df.OrderNumber.where(
        data_df.OrderNumber.str.len().ge(4)
        | ~data_df.OrderNumber.isin(['00010000', '01000010'])
        | ~data_df.OrderNumber.str.contains('12345'),
    '')
    .str.replace(' ', '')
)
```

Comment: But one of my condition is: `OrderNumber` Is NOT any of `'00010000', '01000010'`

Comment: @nam Sorry about that; check now :)